# SQLite Exception: no such column in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-activity, android-sqlite

I wrote an application to update rows in SQlite Db, below is the code for update in data handler:

```
public long updatedata(String ID, String NAME,String NUMBER)
    {
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(name, NAME);
        content.put(number,NUMBER);
        return db.update(table_name, content, "id "+"="+ID, null);

    }
```

now when i need to update a row i used below code:

```
Datahandler data =new Datahandler();
data.open();
long updateresult = data.updatedata(oldID, cloudnames.get(pos), cloudnumbers.get(pos));
data.close();
```

Also assume that the above provided value is exist and valid and also i am sure that there is an id = jo_2 in my database, the problem is when i run the code an exception appear as below:

```
02-19 23:59:34.200: E/SQLiteLog(18485): (1) no such column: jo_2
02-19 23:59:34.205: W/dalvikvm(18485): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b30c08)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[test-service]
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485): Process: com.kaizendroid.bc, PID: 18485
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: jo_2 (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE info SET name=?,number=? WHERE id =jo_2
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:690)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1706)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1654)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at com.kaizendroid.bc.DataHandler.updatedata(DataHandler.java:122)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at com.kaizendroid.bc.MyTestService.getbcfromcloud(MyTestService.java:169)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at com.kaizendroid.bc.MyTestService.get_local_cloud_compare(MyTestService.java:70)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at com.kaizendroid.bc.MyTestService.onHandleIntent(MyTestService.java:49)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
02-19 23:59:34.210: E/AndroidRuntime(18485):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error isn't saying that a value of "jo_2" is missing in the table, but that a *column* named `jo_2` is missing. It sounds like you have some malformed SQL somewhere.

If this is your actual SQL (from the error):

```
UPDATE info SET name=?,number=? WHERE id =jo_2
```

Then you need some quotes around the `jo_2` part:

```
UPDATE info SET name=?,number=? WHERE id = 'jo_2'
```

Without them, SQLite is comparing the column `id` to the **column** `jo_2`, which doesn't exist.

To fix this, you can change this line in your code:

```
return db.update(table_name, content, "id = '" + ID + "'", null);
                        // add quotes here  ^      and ^
```

**EDIT**: [Falmarri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28617973/74757) shows a safer way to fix your code to avoid the error.

Comment: Don't inject the SQL by hand. That's exactly what the 4th parameter of db.update is for.

Comment: @Falmarri: I totally agree. I answered this question with zero Android experience, so the fourth parameter was unknown to me.

Answer (score 1):

You're opening yourself up to SQL injection. Use the built in where clause parameter inserting.

```
public int update (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

So you want

```
return db.update(table_name, content, "id = ?", new String[] {"jo_2"});
```

Answer (score 0):

I  ran into this trouble what you can is this

```
 String originalYearString = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            where= TableName.COL_YEAR_NAME+" = "+"'"+originalYearString+"'";//placing values of the column to be updated in '' is important or else it detects it as a single table column 
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)){
                where+=" AND "+selection;
            }
            rowUpdated=database.update(TABLE_NAME,values,where,selectionArgs);
            break;
```